# How to "pin" html elements to parent, but prevent rotation inheritance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to build a certain UI element based around spinning the control object with various indicators on it. The control is an Object element containing SVG and within the SVG there are `image` tags embedded that are the icons users interact with. When the user spins the element such that the icon is within a "target zone", some function is triggered.

A very very simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/megakoresh/pp7mt1nm/2/

The element is build using CSS `transform: rotate()` property set via javascript and as you can see from the example, all of it's children rotate with it. What I would like to do is to keep them upright, but still change position, as if they were "hanging" from the parent element.

If you go to the fiddle and uncomment the JS code, you can see one solution with `requestAnimationFrame`, but it's really heavy and messy and I really don't like it. Is there any better way to keep elements upright when the parent rotates, but still have them move with it?

### Important:

Ok I think I wasn't clear enough: it's a **rotatable** UI element I am building. The `130deg` there is just an example - **the user can rotate the element to any degree they wish**. I can not simply hardcode those degrees, I have to *prevent* the children from inheriting rotation.

Like Mr. Polywhirl has pointed out, it is something like this:

http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/Alzqe

except the user can grab the wheel and rotate it in any direction themseleves.

Comment: Maybe something like a [CSS Ferris Wheel?](http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/Alzqe).

Comment: Yeah like that. Except like I said: it's a UI element and the user can spin that wheel to any degree they wish. I can't hardcode the degrees, maybe I should make it clearer.

Comment: You can set css property programmatically when event happens.

Comment: That is exactly what I do in the fiddle I linked: like I said I do not like that solution and was wondering if there is anything more efficient than that. If there isn't, I will close the question, but programmatic solution is something I have already done and linked to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript, the answer is to dynamically add negative rotation to the child to compensate the parent.

Without Javascript, use a common container, but don't actually put the sticky element into the rotating one. [The fiddle has been updated with this example](http://jsfiddle.net/pp7mt1nm/3/).

```
<section>
  <div class="block" id="test">
  <p>
  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)
  </p>
  </div>
  <a id="l1" href="#" class="link">Click this!</a>
  <a id="l2" href="#" class="link">No, click this!</a>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {
    transition: transform 1s ease;
}
.block:hover a {
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
}
```